# PHP Date custom script help needed

Tags: php, date

I have to get how many Saturdays and how many Sundays in a given month and pass it to for loop. My input can be like this

```
  HowmanySaturdays("Feb,2010");
```

or

```
  HowmanySaturdays("02,2010");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function HowManySaturdays($month)
{
    $date = explode(',', $month);
    $date = date_parse($date[1] . '-' . $date[0]);
    $days = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $date['month'], $date['year']);
    $timestamp = jdtounix(gregoriantojd($date['month'], 1, $date['year']));
    $date = getdate($timestamp);
    return (floor($days/7)) + ((($days % 7) + $date['wday'] >=7) ? 1 : 0);
}
```

Comment: Hi baruch , thanks for your script. I make a another one . please check the answer if you needed

Answer (score 1):

Brute force method: Iterate over all days of the given month; for any day that is a saturday, increase a counter variable. When done looping, return the counter.

Better method: Find the first saturday in the given month, then increase by 7 until you hit the next month.

Yet better method: find day-of-week of the first day in the given month. If it's not a saturday, increase by the required number of days to reach a saturday. Then proceed using method 2.

Even better: Find the first saturday using method 2. Find the number of days in the month. These two give you the remaining number of days in the month. Divide by 7 and round down.

Comment: hi thanks for your comment, based on your idea made a script. check the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
function HowManyDays($day,$month,$year)
{
    $d = date("t", mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));
    $n = 1;
    $noOfDays = array();
    echo "<b>".$day."'s </b> found in $month,$year <br>";
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $d; $i++) {
        $c = date("l", mktime(0,0,0,$month,$i,$year));
        if (strtolower($c) == strtolower($day)) {
            $noOfDays[$n] = $i."/".$month."/".$year;
            echo "<b>".$c." On ".$i."/".$month."/".$year."</b><br>";
            $n++;
        } else {
            //echo $c." On ".$i."/".$month."/".$year."<br>";
        }

    }
    return $noOfDays;
}

$noOfDays = HowManyDays("Saturday",1,2010);
print_r($noOfDays);
```

This will return days and its date of the month as a array.